# how linux cannot see more than half my ram ? (64bits)

Tags: linux, ram

I've had 8Gb out of 4*4Gb sticks. I've installed some new memory sticks to upgrade to the host to 4*8Gb. However I still have only 16Gb available (out of physical 32GB installed). Whatever the setup is, Linux appears to only see half the installed ram.

There is no hardware issues (the memory has been tested on two other machines)

bios = 32Gb detected
Linux just sees 16GB ram
dmidecode sees all of my 4 sticks

```
# dmidecode -t 17                             
# dmidecode 3.1                                                  
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.                        
SMBIOS 2.7 present.                                            

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: E09028A6
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: CT102464BF160B.C16
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s
Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes        
Memory Device                               
        Array Handle: 0x000D                                                            
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided                                          
        Total Width: 64 bits                
        Data Width: 64 bits                 
        Size: 8192 MB                       
        Form Factor: SODIMM                 
        Set: None                           
        Locator: DIMM1                      
        Bank Locator: BANK 1                
        Type: DDR3                          
        Type Detail: Synchronous            
        Speed: 1600 MT/s                    
        Manufacturer: Unknown               
        Serial Number: E0902887             
        Asset Tag: Unknown                  
        Part Number: CT102464BF160B.C16     
        Rank: 2                             
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s   

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes        
Memory Device                               
        Array Handle: 0x000D                
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided                                          
        Total Width: 64 bits                
        Data Width: 64 bits                 
        Size: 8192 MB                       
        Form Factor: SODIMM                 
        Set: None                           
        Locator: DIMM1                      
        Bank Locator: BANK 2                
        Type: DDR3                          
        Type Detail: Synchronous            
        Speed: 1600 MT/s                    
        Manufacturer: Unknown               
        Serial Number: E09027D2             
        Asset Tag: Unknown                  
        Part Number: CT102464BF160B.C16     
        Rank: 2                             
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s   

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes        
Memory Device                               
        Array Handle: 0x000D                
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided                                          
        Total Width: 64 bits                
        Data Width: 64 bits                 
        Size: 8192 MB                       
        Form Factor: SODIMM                 
        Set: None                           
        Locator: DIMM3                      
        Bank Locator: BANK 3                
        Type: DDR3                          
        Type Detail: Synchronous            
        Speed: 1600 MT/s                    
        Manufacturer: Unknown               
        Serial Number: E0902882             
        Asset Tag: Unknown                  
        Part Number: CT102464BF160B.C16     
        Rank: 2                             
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

Any idea why, as well as any suggestions on how to activate all of it? (currently runs Fedora26/64bits also tested on Debian/64bits)

meminfo :

```
bash-4.4$ cat  /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       16307964 kB
MemFree:         2589188 kB
MemAvailable:    9856496 kB
Buffers:          428964 kB
Cached:          4553096 kB
SwapCached:          132 kB
Active:          7578520 kB
Inactive:        4187932 kB
Active(anon):    3926432 kB
Inactive(anon):   745528 kB
Active(file):    3652088 kB
Inactive(file):  3442404 kB
Unevictable:       24328 kB
Mlocked:           24328 kB
SwapTotal:      15569916 kB
SwapFree:       15528188 kB
Dirty:              3060 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6806540 kB
Mapped:          1573064 kB
Shmem:            363464 kB
Slab:             645716 kB
SReclaimable:     513068 kB
SUnreclaim:       132648 kB
KernelStack:       11552 kB
PageTables:        55452 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    23723896 kB
Committed_AS:   12692532 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      832256 kB
DirectMap2M:    15822848 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

`free -m` results on coherence with `/proc/meminfo`
but `dmidecode` still confirm there are 4 distincts 8Gb ram sticks

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15920        4074        5169         204        6675       12038
```

BIOS is so limited I can just manage boot order. There are no options about memory or anything else. On the BIOS side it confirms 32Gb are present

**Machine model : Aspire V3-772G
The last bios is loaded : V1.15**

That's all I can give useful information `dmesg` analysis did not permit to get anything useful .

Only a warning in loop about kvm/virsh setup : block like this one in loop no other informations at all

```
[12341.196455] set_target_expiration: 30 callbacks suppressed
[12341.196459] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 100012 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12341.306246] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 292092 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12341.704421] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 473064 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12341.914420] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 468345 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12341.924470] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 405938 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12341.996356] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 100012 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12342.096905] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 106350 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12342.135880] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 424319 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12342.406376] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 113630 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
[12342.474998] kvm: vcpu 0: requested 271348 ns lapic timer period limited to 500000 ns
```

my distrib & kernel :

```
[root@h2g2w ~]# cat /etc/*release*
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="26 (Server Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=26
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 26 (Server Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:26"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=26
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=26
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy
VARIANT="Server Edition"
VARIANT_ID=server
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
ROS fuerte (Fuerte Turtle)
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:26
[root@h2g2w ~]# uname -a
Linux h2g2w.local 4.14.11-200.fc26.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 3 13:58:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@h2g2w ~]#
```

but this is useless as I said in commentaries exchanges I tried other distributions even BSD

constructor specs :

```
    Overview
    Specifications

Acer Aspire V3-772G-9829 - 17.3" - Core i7 4702MQ - 8 GB RAM - 1 TB HDD

Part Number: NX.M74AA.002
General

    Packaged Quantity
    1
    Notebook type
    Gaming, HD display, Desktop replacement
    Manufacturer
    Acer

Processor / Chipset

    CPU
    Intel Core i7 (4th Gen) 4702MQ / 2.2 GHz
    Max Turbo Speed
    3.2 GHz
    Number of Cores
    Quad-Core
    Cache
    L3 - 6 MB
    64-bit Computing
    Yes
    Chipset Type
    Mobile Intel HM86 Express
    Features
    Hyper-Threading Technology, Intel Smart Cache, Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0

Cache Memory

    Type
    L3 cache
    Installed Size
    6 MB

Memory

    Max Supported Size
    32 GB
    Technology
    DDR3L SDRAM
    Speed
    1600 MHz / PC3-12800 - 1600 MHz
    Form Factor
    SO-DIMM 204-pin
    Slots Qty
    4

Storage

    Interface
    Serial ATA-300
    Optical Drive
    DVD±RW (±R DL) / DVD-RAM fixed
```

So why Linux (or any other OSes like BSD and so on) detects/activate only 16GB? How can I use the full ram?

Comment: How you're concluding that Linux is detecting only 16 GB out of 32GB?

Comment: only 16Gb are available in linux if you look at /proc/memory or free -m or whatever you want (top, etc...) but physical there is 32Gb installed

Comment: What does `cat /proc/meminfo` say?

Comment: Daft as it may sound, I recently found that taking RAM out and putting it back in again allowed Linux to see some RAM it had forgotten about. I never looked at the output of dmidecode though, so I can’t say if this is relevant to your case.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xsebkeNh   but this is not a hardware issue (ram tested on other machine & allready try to mix stick order)

Comment: other information : I tested to force allocation of 48Gb (to be sure swap +ram is all over used)  this crash at exactly 16Gbram used if I turn off the swap

Comment: Please put all your information into your question. don't leave it here in the comments as it's too easy to overlook. You should rewrite your question so it reads as if you had provided all the information in the first place.

Comment: Have you doublechecked your BIOS settings? Some do allow a *mirror* mode or similar which makes only half of the available RAM visible in the OS. You might want to add your mainboard/bios information to your question or load the defaults or just check for that specific option.

Comment: Check the kernel messages at boot (`dmesg`).

Comment: I did but this just inform me ram is ok & up as 16Gb

Comment: Could be a hardware or motherboard issue

Comment: Maybe but then it should be on motherboard side... 'cause I tested each ram stick on another machine without errors

Comment: Some motherboards are unable to handle more than 16Gbytes. Dive into their documentation.

Comment: In facts I get this machine because it was able to handle 32GB... but it may have few motherboards revision  where only few supports 32Gb.... :) but then why bios & dmidecode are ok about detection ...  ? (luck ? )

Comment: You should **edit your question** to give more details about your hardware: exact processor model, exact mothercard, exact BIOS version, exact DRAM model. Also look into `dmesg` output. Tell what kernel version you are using, etc. Many DRAM3 motherboards are limited to 16Gb.

Comment: It might happen that you cannot use your 32Gb RAM on your hardware!

Comment: I edit the post and as you already read it uses DDR3 ram sticks. I'm trying to get DRAM informations

Comment: Therefore I already read on other forums about hardware issues if bios & demidecode detection is ok then hardware is OK.   & as mentionned above I am in this exact case.

Comment: Adding update. Just upgraded from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30 and lost RAM of 2 modules. `dmidecode -t memory` lists all modules and Fedora 29 also seen all of RAM, so there is something wrong @ OS level. I have Rampage Extreme MB which supports up to 96 GB of RAM, so it is also not a MB fault.

Answer (score 3):

OK finally I found what happens ... it is not really a hardware issue but a refurbished machine downgraded to the motherboard version that is limited at 16GB supported.... inside the "chassis" of the 32GB model.... But it is already capable to detect all the ram sticks ...  but activating only 2 slots.

So I will wait until my next opportunity to get a machine for cheap to get a 32/64Gb one.